# Uncaught Error when inject $cookieStore Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a service in angularjs which seems fine to me but when I inject $cookieStore into the service it gives me an uncaught error and I dont know why this is occurring.

Error:

```
angular.js:36Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24cookieReaderProv…ieReader%20%3C-%20%24cookies%20%3C-%20%24cookieStore%20%3C-%20loginService
```

Service file:

```
myApp.factory('loginService',  ['$q','$http','API_SERVER','$cookieStore',function ($q, $http, API_SERVER,$cookieStore) {
         var login = function(username,passowrd){
         // some code
    },

         var logout = function(username,passowrd){
          //some code
    }


         return {

                    login: function (username, password) {
                        return login(username, password);
                    },

                    logout: function (username, token) {
                        return logout(username, token);
                    },

                };

            }]);
```

If I remove $cookieStore then it works properly. But including the code above throws the error. Also if I add $scope to service it throws an uncaught error.

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
])
```

index.html

```
<script src='{% static "js/angular.min.js" %}'></script>
<script src='{% static "js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.min.js" %}'></script>
<script src='{% static "js/angular-route.min.js" %}'></script>
<script src='{% static "js/angular-animate.min.js" %}'></script>
<script src='{% static "js/angular-resource.min.js" %}'></script>
<script src='{% static "js/angular-cookies.min.js" %}'></script>
<script src='{% static "js/angular-sanitize.min.js" %}'></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Unknown provider: $$cookieReaderProvider <- $$cookieReader <- $cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859779/angularjs-unknown-provider-cookiereaderprovider-cookiereader-cookie)

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a version mismatch.  Make sure all of your angular JS modules match.  (please post the versions of angular-cookies & angular).  With that being said you say you are using 1.5x, but your error is clearly 1.2.x

-- original answer:

You should be injecting `$cookies` versus `$cookieStore`

Documentation for [$cookies](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies).  `$cookieStore` has been [deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore).

Comment: Update both references.

Comment: its not problem of $cookieStore and $cookies  if i remove both and add $scope then its give same error.

Comment: myApp.factory('loginService', ['$q', '$http','API_SERVER','$cookies',function ($q, $http, API_SERVER,$cookies) {  .......... }

Comment: Your error says cookieReader but no where in your code do I see cookie reader?

Comment: Can you post the versions of ngcookie. Is it 1.2x as well?

Comment: its angularjs  v1.5.5

Comment: if i used $window instead of $cookies it works and if i used $scope it again through scope provider error. I think its some things else happend which i dont know

Comment: @RahulDev  your error message is not 1.5.5 , if you are using 1.5.5 then my original answer is correct.  cookieStore was deprecated.   Look at the message in your answer `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/`

Comment: yes, I got it there is version conflict error of angularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.5.6 (latest angular 1):

> Note: The $cookieStore service is deprecated. Please use the $cookies
>   service instead.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore

Comment: His error is angular 1.2.x  (but I agree its been deprecated)

Comment: yes i replaced $cookieStore to $cookie but same error occurs